# Marshmallow: How can I override this python class's constructor?

Tags: python, serialization, overriding, marshmallow

Below is my python [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) serializer which I'm using in my SQLAlchemy-based application.

```
import simplejson
from marshmallow import Schema
class MySerializer(Schema):
    class Meta:
        json_module = simplejson
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')

    field3 = fields.Method('get_field3')

    def get_field3(self, this_obj):
        return "Hello"
```

Here is how I call this serializer:

```
my_argument = 1
items=MySerializer(documents=list_of_my_objects, many=True).data
```

Now, I want to change the serializer such that it takes an additional argument (I will pass in `my_argument`) and if the value of that argument is 1, return `"Goodbye"` in place of `"Hello"`. How can I do that?

In particular, I don't know how I can pass in an argument to this marshamallow Schema such that it is available from inside`get_field3`. I know I need to override the `__init__()` method. But I'm not sure what it should look like. I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
def __init__(self, documents, many, my_arg):
    self.my_arg = my_arg
    super(Schema, self).__init__(documents, many=many)

def get_field3(self, this_obj):
    self.my_arg == 1:
        return "Goodbye"
    else:
        return "Hello"
```

This was the stack-trace I got:

```
my_project/my_models/serializers.pyc in __init__(self, documents, many, my_arg)
---> 25         super(Schema, self).__init__(documents, many=many)

my_virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.pyc in __init__(self, obj, extra, only, exclude, prefix, strict, many, skip_missing, context)
--> 273             self._update_fields(self.obj, many=many)

my_virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.pyc in _update_fields(self, obj, many)
--> 636         ret = self.__filter_fields(field_names, obj, many=many)

my_virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.pyc in __filter_fields(self, field_names, obj, many)
--> 683                         attribute_type = type(obj_dict[key])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pop added arg from kwargs to avoid any errors (you can pass any kwargs to method redefined this way):

```
class MySerializer(Schema):
    # ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_arg = kwargs.pop('my_arg') if 'my_arg' in kwargs else None
        super(Schema, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

now you can pass custom kwarg (**keyword** argument, not positional) to create objects:

```
MySerializer(documents=list_of_my_objects, many=True, my_arg=1)
```